# How to scale sprite and use it later [like saving as png]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, scale

I'm making a small program that using JSON file slices texture and combine slices into one sprite. Slicing works great but combining is hard. The problem is that some sprites are scaled. The only way to scale the sprite I found is by using Transform. But Transform changes rendered sprite, not the original.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);
texture.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "/Animation/raw/", "test.png")));
var rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
var sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, rect, Vector2.one * 0.5f);
sprite.scale= new Vector3(1, 8, 1);

Texture2D newText = new Texture2D((int)sprite.rect.width,(int)sprite.rect.height);
Color[] newColors = sprite.texture.GetPixels((int)sprite.rect.x,
                    (int)sprite.rect.y,
                    (int)sprite.rect.width,
                    (int)sprite.rect.height);
newText.SetPixels(newColors);
newText.Apply();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/Animation/"+"test.png", newText.EncodeToPNG());
```

Or you need to do something with Transform?

Also, I'm not really sure how to combine sprites, my idea is using `texture.SetPixel(x, y, color);`